# concurency makes my program slow

Tags: go

I've simple program in go, that sumarize total distance and time spend in polygon, and I'm trying to make it even faster.

https://gist.github.com/mochja/cf5f477348ab8fde1a4a

I was trying to create goroutine, first thing what i've tried was create a goroutine around pnpolys if statement, so it should create goroutine for every data in every polygon and halt, but I run into a problem with exc. time its about ~40x slower. Maybe I can't create great number of goroutines or I did miss something.

code what have tried, simple test just, why my execution time is bigger than no-goroutine version ?

```
for di := range d {
    data := d[di]
    go pnpoly(len(v[pi][0]), v[pi][0], v[pi][1], data.Longitude, data.Latitude)
}
```

Comment: Have you set the GOMAXPROCS to use more than one core ? (http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) Goroutines are concurrent but not necessarily parallel. If you have only one OS thread, the runtime continuously looses time switching between the different goroutines, without any speed benefit.

Comment: oh, thank you. seems to be fine now.